# Color Excel cell based on COUNTIF function

Tags: excel-formula, highlight, countif

I'm trying to color excel cell based on my `COUNTIF`-function. There are many examples to count cell based on color but i need to fill cell with color based on `COUNTIF`-function. I have 30 names in a column. At the end i have `COUNTIF`-function to count total number of names with last name Malik. This works and i get number 8 from this function. Now I would like to highlight these 8 cells, so they are easy to find. If colorfill can be combined with `COUNTIF`-function, it would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

conditional formatting -> formula -> `=isnumber(search("Malik",a1;0))` should work. delete dollar signs for the search cell. Adapt the celladdress to your needs.

You could also use `=COUNTIF(A1,"*Malik*")` or even use `=COUNTIFS(A1,"*Malik*",B1,"<"&today())`

Comment: It worked and didn't worked at the same time I still like to see if there is a function to fill color and count together. i'm also using CONUNTIF function with date less than 3/1/2020 (=COUNTIF(D2:D28,"<=3/1/2020") and conditional formatting doesn't work for this.

Comment: thank you, conditional formatting worked on date condition also. just select cell value less then or equal to and type your date (3/1/2020) in value.

Comment: how can i fill color in entire row rather than just the cell.?

Comment: It depends on the range it is applied to from the window before.